# Select records within a group, but keep group in tact

Tags: crystal-reports

I am writing a report to capture patient bed assignment history.  As an inpatient, a patient may be transferred from bed to bed multiple times within one visit.  I want to identify all patients (and the complete transfer history) where the patient was transferred to an ICU bed.  I've gotten to the point where I've identified the bed history for all patients, but now I cannot figure out how to exclude those groups where the patient was not transferred to an ICU bed.  I want to only see the groups (intact) where patient has been transferred to ICU at least once within their inpatient visit.

I'm thinking I need to write a formula within Report>Select Expert>Group, but not sure how to start.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's an example of my current output.

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8665870/revisions) is close to what I am looking for but can't get my formula correct.

Comment: We've done similar tasks to this by grouping by patient id and using a line in our select expert such as `not {table.column} in (bed indexes to exclude separated by commas)` to exclude patients where one of their ID's rows has a value that makes us want to leave them out

Comment: Try grouping by Patient ID and then try this line in select expert record and then select expert group, let me know what happens from there. In the meantime I'll poke around at some old reports

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Comment: Hi Jackson, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi Jackson, thanks for your reply, but I cannot exclude the beds I do not want because I am looking for all the entire history.  So if a patient starts in bed 100A, transfers to ICU1A, and then to bed 200A, I need to see all of those beds.  I am grouping by visit and need to see only those patients that occupied an ICU bed along with the other beds that they occupied during their stay in the hospital.

Comment: Hi Siva, no my issue is not solved.  Still can't figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: ok, I just figured out how to do it.  I created a formula for ICU beds.  "IF {pt.loc.shortname} starts with ICU" then 1 else 0"  Then I inserted summary at the visit group level.  then within select I said "Sum ({@ICUbed},{table.visit}) > 0"

Comment: Correction:ok, I just figured out how to do it.  I created a formula for ICU beds.  "IF {pt.loc.shortname} starts with "ICU"" then 1 else 0"  Then I inserted summary of @ICUBed at the visit group level.  then within report>select expert>group I wrote "Sum ({@ICUbed},{table.visit}) > 0"